# What are virtualization and KVM?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Can anyone explain this:

1. What is virtualization?
2. What KVM Kernel Virtual Machine?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Oh fine next time sure i do that sorry for this time

Comment: @Danatela Since KVM *is* a virtualization solution, these are hardly separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualization is a very broad term on which everyone could interpret in a different way.

So let me quote the following from the official [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/index.html) and if you need more details; I could guide you to more resources.

***Virtualization** is being adopted in many different environments and situations.

If you are a developer, virtualization can provide you with a **contained environment** where you can safely do almost any sort of development safe from messing up your main working environment.

If you are a systems administrator, you can use virtualization to more easily **separate your services** and move them around based on **demand**.

The default virtualization technology supported in Ubuntu is **KVM**.

KVM **requires** virtualization extensions built into Intel and AMD hardware.

Xen is also supported on Ubuntu. Xen can take advantage of virtualization extensions, **when available**, but can also be used on hardware without virtualization extensions.

**Qemu** is another popular solution for hardware without virtualization extensions.*

Comment: Note : KVM stands for Kernel-Based Virtual Machine. and the link provided by @handuel was actually the same I was going to provide for details on KVM :) but I want to highlight that KVM requires a virtualization capable hardware (processor); i.e Intel VT or AMD-V. but other Virtualization technologies -like Xen; can work on both.

Answer (score 1):

Visualization is running an operating system on top of another operating system. It is a good way to try out new OS's, and several programs exist to let you do this, such as virtual box. KVM is a kernel module (similar to a driver), that allows linux to use build in parts of computer hardware that are designed specially for the purpose of visualization.

Comment: thanks for u answer could give an example for this and i like to know little brief about that is it possible

Comment: I am not that knowledgeable on this topic, however you could try reading this: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page